# while run the ng server --open command in terminal i got this error "events.js 174 throw er; //Unhandled 'error' event "

Tags: angular, npm

while run the ng server --open command in terminal  i got this error "events.js 174 throw er; //Unhandled 'error' event "

F:\Nagarjun\Angular\todos-demo>ng s -o
    10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
    i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
    i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 45.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 264 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 829 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.18 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-08-27T08:30:35.166Z - Hash: a1585b9cfd019ac5972e - Time: 16317ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `ng server --open`? I've seen cmd like this - `ng serve --open`

Comment: Which version of npm, node.js and angular do you use? And do you use windows?